# Passing null to JPA OneToOne Persist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, jpa-2.0

I have an HR System that will add and update the database. I have a problem in my JPA relationship in persist and merging whenever I would pass a null value on it. In our requirement it can be nullable, but when even I enter a null value to it for example the departments the following error occurs:

> [RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction]
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance
>   before flushing: models.db.Employee.Department -> models.db.Department

For reference here are my entity class
Employee.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEES")
public class Employee {

@Id
public Integer EMPLOYEE_ID;

public String FIRST_NAME;

public String LAST_NAME;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name= "JOB_ID")
public Job Job;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="MANAGER_ID")
public Employee Manager;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name= "DEPARTMENT_ID")
public Department Department;

}
```

Job.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="JOBS")
public class Job {

@Id
public String JOB_ID;

public String JOB_TITLE;

}
```

Department.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DEPARTMENTS")
public class Department {

@Id
public Integer DEPARTMENT_ID;

public String DEPARTMENT_NAME;

@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="MANAGER_ID")
public Employee Manager;
}
```

AppModel.class save()

```
public void save () {
int intSize = listSize + 1;
for (int i= 0; i < intSize; i++) {
Employee employee = new Employee();

Job job = new Job();
job.JOB_ID = employees.get("empJobId" + i);

Department dept = new Department();
dept.DEPARTMENT_ID = ParseUtil.stringToInt(employees.get("empDeptId" + i));

Employee manager = new Employee();
manager.EMPLOYEE_ID = ParseUtil.stringToInt(employees.get("empMgrId" + i));

Integer intId =  ParseUtil.stringToInt(employees.get("empId" + i));
employee.EMPLOYEE_ID = intId;
employee.FIRST_NAME = employees.get("empFirstName" + i);
employee.LAST_NAME = employees.get("empLastName" + i);
employee.Job = job;
employee.Department = dept;
employee.Manager = manager;
EmpDomain.updateEmp(employee);
}
}
```

And EmpDomain.updateEmp()

```
public static void updateEmp(Employee employee) {
  JPA.em().merge(employee);
}
```

Im only a newbie on play 2, jpa persistance so i dont know how to fix the exception error please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to map those dependencies as bi-directional.

In that case you have to tell the persistence provider which is the owning / owned side of the relationship.

If Employee is the owned side for example then you should change the mapping to:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "Manager", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
public Department Department;
```

also if you are merging from the Employee entity then you should put at least persist and merge cascading option.

Comment: I dont really get how jpa relationship works. what a uni-directional or bi. my goal is to convert this Oracle SQL code to JPA Merge. 

   `UPDATE` 
   `EMPLOYEES` 
   `SET` 
   `FIRST_NAME = ?, `
    `LAST_NAME = ?,`
   `JOB_ID = ?, `
   `MANAGER_ID = ?,` 
   `DEPARTMENT_ID = ?,`
   `WHERE`
   `EMPLOYEE_ID = ?;`

But i dont really get JPA Relationship works. in mapping and other stuff. i somehow got it to update but when i dont put a value on the departments or manager or jobs the rollback exception occurs.

Comment: try to add the cascade options on the emplyee as given